# Displaying Timer using Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, nstimer, countdowntimer

I am trying to display the **Timer** and **Countdown Timer from  59 seconds  to  0 seconds** in decrease order and also displaying the alert message after the count completes. But there is a problem in displaying the countdown that is its display the alert message before ***0:1*** seconds .can anyone help to solve this.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module('MyApp',[])
    app.controller('MyController',function($scope,$window,$timeout){

        var tim;
        $scope.totalsec = 60;
        var countdowntime= function(){
            $scope.totalsec--;
            $scope.min = parseInt($scope.totalsec / 60, 10);
            $scope.sec = $scope.totalsec - ($scope.min * 60);

            if($scope.sec >0){
                tim = $timeout(countdowntime, 1000);
            } else if($scope.sec ==0){
                $timeout.cancel(tim);
                $window.alert("Time Up");
            }
        };
        countdowntime();

    });

</script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">  
    countertime:{{min}}:{{sec}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($scope.sec >0){
```

should be:

```
 if($scope.sec ==0){
```

So "1" doesn't fire it. "1" is bigger than "0".

Comment: Hi . Its not working when I keeping  if($scope.sec ==0) instead of if($scope.sec >0)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function AlbumCtrl($scope,$timeout) {
$scope.counter = 0;
$scope.onTimeout = function(){
    $scope.counter++;
    mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
}
var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);

$scope.stop = function(){
    $timeout.cancel(mytimeout);
}
}
```

Comment: can u please keep the above code in "https://jsfiddle.net/" show that how it works